# Wie kann 'abdecken' sowohl 'to cover' als auch 'to uncover' bedeuten?

Tags: meaning

Wiktionary sagt [hier](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abdecken):

> **abdecken** (*third-person singular simple present* deckt ab, *past tense* deckte ab, *auxiliary* haben, *past participle* abgedeckt)
>
> 1. to **cover**: Ich muss noch die Leiche abdecken - Now I have to cover the corpse.
> 2. to cover costs: Das deckt kaum die Kosten ab. - That barely covers the costs.
> 3. to **uncover**, untile: Der Sturm deckte die Dächer ab. - The storm uncovered the roofs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [ab-](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ab-&submit_button=Suche&view=1)

Das Präfix *„ab-“* wird unter anderem in der Bedeutung *„weg-“* (*to take away*) eingesetzt. So erklären sich die meisten der mit [abdecken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abdecken) verbundenen Bedeutungen:

> - Der Sturm deckte die Dächer ab: *Der Sturm nahm den Dächern die Ziegel **weg***.
> - Das Zimmermädchen deckt das Bett ab: *Sie nimmt die Bettdecke **weg***.

Aber es gibt noch die andere, übertragene Bedeutung:

> - Ich muss noch die Leiche abdecken: *Ich muss die Leiche mit einem Tuch bedecken, um neugierige Blicke von ihr **weg**zunehmen.*
> - Empfindliche Pflanzen werden mit Zweigen abgedeckt: *Die Pflanzen werden mit Zweigen bedeckt, um den Einfluss der Kälte **weg**zunehmen.*

Es gibt noch eine Reihe weiterer, seltenerer Bedeutungen. Früher hatte z. B. *abdecken* die Bedeutung, Tieren nach dem Schlachten die Haut abzuziehen. Dies findet sich heute aber nur noch in der ebenfalls veraltenden Berufsbezeichnung *[„Abdecker“](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Abdecker)*.

Somit wird hier der Begriff *„abdecken“* zwar oft synonym mit *„bedecken“* verwendet, immer wird aber damit zugleich auch ein anderer externer Einfluss weggenommen.

Sollte man unsicher sein, redet man besser von *bedecken*, *zudecken*, *überdecken*. Nicht umsonst führt [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abdecken) hier das Beispiel der Leiche an, bei der das Bedecken mit einem Tuch eben nicht dieselbe Funktion hat wie die einer Bettdecke. Im Bett deckt man sich **zu**, aber niemals **ab**.

Comment: Ich habe den ersten Teil von Ihren Antwort versteht. Aber ich will eigentlich gerade schlafen, weil es die tiefste Nacht ist. Zudem benötige ich ein Wörterbuch, weiter anzudauern. Aber Ihre Antwort scheint, sehr gut zu sein. Danke!

Comment: Man kann von Glück sterben! Ich kann in Wörter nicht sagen, wie glücklich ich im Moment bin. Aber das bedeutet nicht, dass ich habe versucht, die Antwort wiederzulesen. Meine Prüfungen lassen mir nicht. Allerdings, danke schön!

Comment: Also habe ich einige Frage von Ihne neuen und korrigierten Aufsatz. Soll ich die hier oder als andere Frage fragen? Außerdem, tut mir Leid. Wirklich war es ein dummer Fehler, "verstanden" als "versteht" zu schreiben. Ich hoffe, ich bin richtig jetzt.

Comment: @AnuragKalia: Wenn Du weiter Fragen hast, dann frag doch einfach mit einer [neuen Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Du bekommst sicher eine gute Antwort!